# Grouping query results by count

Tags: mysql, sorting, count

I am trying to get results from a table grouped and sorted by count. I've got the following table:

```
┌───────────┬──────────┐
│ [sub_key] │ [sub_id] │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│  subkey   │ abc      │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│  subkey   │ abd      │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│  subkey   │ abe      │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│  subkey   │ abc      │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│  subkey   │ abc      │
├───────────┼──────────┤
│  subkey   │ abd      │
└───────────┴──────────┘
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
subkey | abc | 3
subkey | abd | 2
subkey | abe | 1
```

Any suggestions on what my query should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [sub_key], [sub_id], count(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY [sub_key], [sub_id]
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As a solution please try executing the following SQL query

```
select sub_key,sub_id,count(sub_key) as counter 
from TABLE_NAME group by sub_key,sub_id order by counter desc
```